# Как настроить xdebug на Ubuntu 18/19 + Nginx для VSCodium?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, php7, xdebug, vscodium

Версия PHP:

```
PHP 7.2.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Dec 18 2019 14:58:00) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.26-1+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

Установил `xdebug`:

```
sudo apt install php-xdebug
```

В **VSCodium** установил необходимый плагин(`PHP Debug`).
В файл `/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php.ini` дописал:

```
[XDebug]
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_mode=req
```

Перезапустил PHP и Nginx:

```
sudo service php7.2-fpm restart
sudo service nginx restart
```

Вывод `phpinfo()`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создал `lounch.json`в директорию `.vscode/`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Listen for XDebug",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "port": 9000
    },
    {
      "name": "Launch currently open script",
      "type": "php",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${file}",
      "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
      "port": 9000
    }
  ]
}
```

Почему не поехало?

Comment: Попробуйте в ini добавить путь к xdebug, который установили. Пример: zend_extension = xdebug.so или полный путь zend_extension="/usr/lib/php7/20090626/xdebug.so

Comment: Я добавил. `Xdebug` появился в `phpinfo()`. D `VSCodium` поставил точку останова, запустил `Listen for XDebug`. Но при запуске скрипта не происходит остановка. Или я, что-то не понимаю?

Comment: попробуйте добавить в созданный файл launch.json параметры localSourceRoot и serverSourceRoot. Пример:             "localSourceRoot": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "serverSourceRoot": "/app/public" Так же предполагается, что у Вас установлен VS Code Extension

Comment: На какой уровень (в какой параметр)?

Comment: Писать долго, вот пример. https://localbyflywheel.com/community/t/how-to-get-xdebug-working-with-visual-studio-code/3493/2

Comment: `VSCodium` пишет, что `localSourceRoot, serverSourceRoot` устарело.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102676/discussion-between----and-denis640kb).